# How can i compare two arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, function

so my problem is that i need to compare two arrays. Compare them like this,  if the array 1 have values - 1 2 3 and the array 2 have values 3 2 1 the programm finds it as equal.  Right now i only make it work on this if array 1 values  - 1 2 3 and array 2 values - 1 2 3 , then it finds arrays equal, but i need to search arrays who have similar values but not excatly in the same place. 
Right now i use this code below to search for equal values in arrays.  But it wont work if you need to search equal values but in different positions. Hope most of you will understand my problem. And sorry for bad English, its not my native language.

```
 int skaitluParbaude(int loterija[], int speletajs[])
 {
int match = 0;

for (int x = 0; x < SKAITS; ++x)
{
    if (loterija[x] == speletajs[x])
        match = match + 1;

}
return match;
}
```

Comment: sort the arrays then compare

Comment: Might want to use a Standard Library container for those rather than slinging around C-style arrays like that.

Comment: There are a few questions you need to answer:  1) Can these arrays be sorted before searching?  2) If you aren't allowed to sort the arrays, can you use an intermediate data structure (i.e. a `set`) to calculate if two arrays have equal values?

Comment: Also, your question asks whether the two arrays are equal, but you're returning a number denoting the number of matched items.  If you want to determine if the arrays are "equal", shouldn't you be returning either `true` or `false`?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways that I can think of:

1. Sort the arrays before comparing. Once sorted, you can compare the elements starting from index 0. If you find a mismatch, the arrays don't compare equal.
2. Create two `std::set`s from the arrays and use `std::set::operator==`.

   ```
   std::set<int> s1(std::begin(array1), std::end(array1));
   std::set<int> s2(std::begin(array2), std::end(array2));
   s1 == s2;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use the exact method you are using if it is working for `{1,2,3}` compared with `{1,2,3}`.

But: sort both arrays before you start comparing. This is the trick and here is how you sort an array:

```
std::sort(YourArray.begin(), YourArray.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort the both arrays and apply your method as following:

```
int skaitluParbaude(int loterija[], int speletajs[])
 {
int match = 0;

sort(loterija,loterija + x);
sort(speletajs,speletajs + x);


for (int x = 0; x < SKAITS; ++x)
{
    if (loterija[x] == speletajs[x])
        match = match + 1;

}
return match;
}
```

for this include `<algorithm>` as header file. and `x` is size of array.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the size of the array beforehand you can use hashing, replace INT_MAX with the maximum element of your array.

```
bool similar(int loterija[], int speletajs[]){

    int arr[INT_MAX], flag = 0;
    std::fill(begin(arr),end(arr),0);

    for (int x = 0; x < SKAITS; ++x) 
        arr[loterija[x]] = 1;
    for (int x = 0; x < SKAITS; ++x) 
        if(arr[speletajs[x]] != 1) {
             flag = 1;
             break;
        }
    if(flag == 0)
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}
```